# Wrong coordinates using HTML Geolocation API

Tags: html, geolocation

I am trying to use HTML5 Geolocation API on Windows 10 using Chrome as a browser.
I am having problems with getting right longitude and latitude. I have tried also using some web applications such as [where-am-i.me](https://www.where-am-i.me/) but it giving the same result. Only Google gives the right location. How I can fix this, can we use some Google API for this?

```
enter code here
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    $(".latitude").text(position.coords.latitude);
    $(".longitude").text(position.coords.longitude);
  showMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}
```

Comment: The problem is the browser does not have a GPS chip to use so it's trying to work it out from the information the IPS gives, if you ran this code on your phone it would use the GPS chip on the phone and i think if you have GPS connected to your PC it will use that. I think Google is also pulling information from your smartphone connected to google. Google always reports my location as my logged in phones location not the location of the PC im using.